# Pause between text display

Tags: java, sleep, pause

So I'm creating a text based game, and I'm having a hard time trying to find a way to pause between text displays.. I know that thread sleep would work, but I don't want to have to do this for hundreds of lines of text. Here is what I have, but is there a much more simple way of doing this?

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello?");
        //pause here
        System.out.println("Is this thing on?");
        /**Obviously I have a pause here, but I dont want to have to use this every time.*/
        try {
            Thread.sleep(x);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Now, what is your name?");
    }
}
```

Comment: To refactor the code you can just create your own **print()** method that will do the pause after printing text

Comment: Write a method, call it `pause`, maybe allow the caller to pass in `int` value indicating the amount of time they want to pause

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply wrap it in another class?

```
class DisplayWrapper {
    private final static long DEFAULT_PAUSE_MS = 250;

    public static void outputWithPause(String text, long ms) {
        System.out.println(text);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void show(String text) {
        outputWithPause(text. DEFAULT_PAUSE_MS);
    }
}

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayWrapper.show("Hello?");
    DisplayWrapper.show("Is this thing on?");
    DisplayWrapper.show("Now, what is your name?");
}
```

Comment: I don't believe creating an entire class for this one functionality is a good idea or good design. Classes should encompass more functionality than a single function . This should be written in a function itself

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

You can use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    writeIn(timer, 3000, "Hello?");
    writeIn(timer, 6000, "Is this thing on?");
    writeIn(timer, 12000, "Now, what is your name?");
    closeTimerIn(timer, 13000); // clean exit
}

private static void writeIn(Timer timer, final int millis, final String text){
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, millis);
}

private static void closeTimerIn(final Timer timer, final int millis){
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, millis);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As m.antkowicz has mentioned in a comment, you'll want to create a print method. I've provided an example:

```
void printAndSleep(String string, int sleepTimeMs) {
  System.out.println(string);
  Thread.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
}
```

Now any time you want to print, just use the printAndSleep method we made above. Like so:

```
printAndSleep("Hello?", 1000); // Print and pause for 1 second
printAndSleep("Is this thing on?", 2000); // Print and pause for 2 seconds
```